# flutter firebaseauth exception issue

Tags: flutter

Im relatively new to flutter and I'm trying to catch the auth errors while logging in and want to show it in my login screen. I'm doing all the authentication services from another file and i want to get the exception from there and onto my login screen

this is from my authservice class

```
Future loginWithEmailpasswd(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      message=e.toString();

    }
```

when i press the login button and pass the value to the authservice class, if there is any exception,i want to get the message from authservice to the login screen

```
class StudentLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  StudentLoginScreen({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _StudentLoginScreenState createState() => _StudentLoginScreenState();
}

final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class _StudentLoginScreenState extends State<StudentLoginScreen> {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String message = '';
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  //SharedPreferences usertype;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: HexColor(studentPrimaryColour),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                showAlert(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                HeadingText(
                  text: 'Login',
                  size: 60.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                RoundedInputField(
                  hintText: "Email",
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Oops! you left this field empty' : null,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    email = val;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                RoundedInputField(
                  hintText: "Password",
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Oops! you left this field empty' : null,
                  boolean: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    password = val;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  width: size.width * 0.8,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                    child: FlatButton(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                          dynamic result = await _authService
                              .loginWithEmailpasswd(email, password);
                          print(email);
                          print(password);
                          if (result != null) {
                            print('logged in');
                          } else {
                            print('error logging in');
                            setState(() {
                              message = // initialize value from authservice
                            });
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'login',
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            color: HexColor(studentPrimaryColour),
                            fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    widget.toggleView();
                  },
                  child: HeadingText(
                    text: 'register?',
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 10,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showAlert() {
    if (_message != null) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.error_outline_rounded),
            Expanded(
                child: AutoSizeText(
              _message,
              maxLines: 3,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }
}
```

is there any possible way without implementing the authservice in my login screen?

Comment: Where do you call the ```loginWithEmailpasswd``` method? Please edit your question with this part of the code.

Comment: @Naslausky done it, is there a way?

Comment: If you want to break down the application into services, you must create classes to keep their state. And you should inject these classes into your application. You can use any state management package for this. For example: Provider or Bloc packages.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and most elegant way to do it would be as stated in the comments. To break your application into services and models. You can use these models together with any [State Management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) approach.

You can set a model class that may have the result of the authentication, or the error that it provided. This should be what's returned by the connection wrapper.

But, an educative and easy suggestion (and **not** elegant in any way) would be to [rethrow](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-rethrow-to-rethrow-a-caught-exception) the exception and catching it again on the outside:

```
Future loginWithEmailpasswd(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
```

And, on the button callback:

```
[...]
Try{
    dynamic result = await _authService
                              .loginWithEmailpasswd(email, password);    
    print('logged in');
}on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
          message = e.toString();
      });
    }
}
[...]
```

As I said, this is not elegant or readable at all. I'm post this answer as an alternative using rethrow.